# how to access nested objects in json and create HTML table

Tags: jquery, json, azure, nested

i am trying to convert json data from azure ML webservice into a html table i would like to get an array with ColumnNames and then the values where i can do for each

i have been looking at the map function and i can get an array back on a less complex json

```
var Jdata = [{ 'Results': { 'output1': { 'type': 'table', 'value': { 'ColumnNames': ['Survived', 'Sex', 'Age', 'Scored Labels', 'Scored Probabilities'], 'ColumnTypes': ['Int32', 'String', 'Nullable`1', 'Int32', 'Double'], 'Values': [['0', 'value', '34', '1', '0.925747632980347']] } } } }];

            var ColumnList = Jdata.map(function (task, index, array) {

                return task.ColumnNames;

            });

            alert(ColumnList);


            //var TestData = [{ 'name': 'Write for Envato Tuts+', 'duration': 120 }, { 'name': 'Work out', 'duration': 60 }, { 'name': 'Procrastinate on Duolingo', 'duration': 240 }];

            //var TestData_names = TestData.map(function (task, index, array) {

            //    return task.name;

            //});

            //alert(TestData_names);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your json is already in parse jquery object form. you can simply use below function to browse through column names

```js
var json = [
  {'Results': {
    'output1':
    { 
      'type': 'table','value': 
      { 
    'ColumnNames': ['Survived', 'Sex', 'Age', 'Scored Labels', 'Scored Probabilities'],
    'ColumnTypes': ['Int32', 'String', 'Nullable', 'Int32', 'Double'], 
    'Values':      ['0', 'value', '34', '1', '0.925747632980347']
      } 
   } 
} 
}];

console.log(json[0].Results.output1.value.ColumnNames);
console.log(json[0].Results.output1.value.Values);
// expected output: 42
```

Above mentioned code would give output lie below:-

[image]

After that you can simply user Jquery.each function to iterate over column and values

```
jQuery.each( obj, function( i, val )
```

Let me know if you need any help.Hope it helps.

**MV**